# Data series - how to pull out specific data relating to times within a time series

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some speed data which relates to time (running clock). I am trying to separate the last 15 minutes of the data series to run some simple descriptive statistics on (rolling_averages) etc.

My code is below for the entire data series - I calculated rolling averages for 1,3 and 5 minute time epochs. I need to run the same but only on the last 15 minutes of the match.

Here is what I have so far:

```
library(dplyr)
rolling_averages <- john %>%
  
  group_by(Game, Half) %>%
  
  # create new columns showing the rolling averages over 1, 3, and 5 minutes
  mutate(`1min` = rollmean(`Speed..m.s.`, 600, fill = NA, align = "right") * 60
  
  # remove all columns except these ones
  select(Time, Game, Half, `1min`, `3min`, `5min`) %>%

Player.Display.Name     Time     Speed..m.s.   Game    Half
                 S    00:33:17    2.430557     A          1
2                S    00:33:17    2.488891     A          1
3                S    00:33:17    2.580558     A          1
4                S    00:33:17    2.530558     A          1
5                S    00:33:17    2.488891     A          1
6                S    00:33:17    2.430557     A          1
>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you edit your question and add a sample of your data using `dput()`? Also, make sure you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for the advice - how do i add some data? :/ how do i use the dput()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: haha so, im really, really new to R. Im trying to use the dput function, but its producing lots of data, if though im specifying the first 1:4 rows....

Comment: code: dput(smith[1:4, ]),c(2,3,4)])

Comment: You can also use `head(your_data)`.

Comment: I am sorry, so the head function brings the column names - but how do skim the data to provide you with an example?

Comment: Just post it with the column names. Edit your question with the output from `head()`. If people are able to see what you data looks like, you will get better answers.

Comment: Player.Display.Name     Time Speed..m.s.    Game Half - like this?

Comment: think ive done it haha?

Comment: Yes, looks better now. Thumbs up.

Comment: lets hope i get some help haha! i could edit the document in excel and trim the last 15 mins but that defeats the object of code, right? Thank you for your help

Comment: `dput(smith[1:4,2:4])`?

Comment: How to share data is answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example Did you read it completely?

Comment: yeah i read it - have i not done this right? also, any guidance on my actual question rather than how i have asked it?